# Use wkhtml2pdf in asp.net core docker image

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

I'm working on an asp.net core 3 project, and I use Rotativa to generate pdf files.

When I run on Windows, wkhtml2pdf.exe works fine, but when I try to run the app in a linux docker image, I have this error :

```
Exception: /app/Rotativa/wkhtmltopdf: error while loading shared libraries: libjpeg.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I use the default Dockerfile (generated by Visual Studio).

I think I have to install libjpeg in the image, but I don't know how to do it.

I tried to install it with apt-get in the Dockerfile, but there's an error :

```
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install -y libjpeg-dev' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

How can I make wkhtml2pdf work in my docker image ?

Comment: The command should be a step in your Dockerfile, such that the actual built image ends up with that dependency. However, that's going to require separate Dockerfiles: one for building a Linux container and one for building a Windows container. You can combine the images into a multi-platform image in your registry, if you like, but you'll need to build each separately on the platform they belong to, i.e. Windows with the Windows Docker engine and Linux with the Linux Docker engine. You can actually do both with Docker for Windows, but you'll need to switch between Linux and Windows containers.

Comment: @glacasa, were you able to solve this? I am in a similar situation where I need to use Rotativa in my application hosted on Azure Linux environment.